# I use Poetry for dependency management and want to build a Docker container - should I be running Poetry in the Docker container?

Tags: docker, python-packaging, python-poetry

Should I be running Poetry inside Docker, or should I be using pip, pipx, or something similar instead?

Should I be building wheels, or tarballs and passing them into the Docker container instead of running pip or poetry inside the Docker container?

Here's an example of one of the Dockerfiles that I tried, but never got to work - the environment is broken, and I have no idea why:

```
FROM python:3.10

# Configure Poetry
ENV POETRY_VERSION=1.2.0
ENV POETRY_HOME=/opt/poetry
ENV POETRY_VENV=/opt/poetry-venv
ENV POETRY_CACHE_DIR=/opt/.cache

# Install poetry separated from system interpreter
RUN python3 -m venv $POETRY_VENV \
    && $POETRY_VENV/bin/pip install -U pip setuptools \
    && $POETRY_VENV/bin/pip install poetry==${POETRY_VERSION}

# Add `poetry` to PATH
ENV PATH="${PATH}:${POETRY_VENV}/bin"

WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies
COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml ./
RUN poetry install

# Run your app
COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "./entrypoint.sh" ]
```

`entrypoint.sh` contains:

```
poetry run blah
```

In this case, the problem is that the virtualenv is broken, and I have no idea why:

```
$ docker run blah/blah:latest
The virtual environment found in /app/.venv seems to be broken.
Recreating virtualenv blah-9TtSrW0h-py3.10 in /opt/.cache/virtualenvs/blah-9TtSrW0h-py3.10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 992, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  ...
    import dateutil.parser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dateutil'
```

Should I even be using Poetry within Docker?  Should I use pip or pipx instead?

What are you supposed to do when you want to run a Python application in a container?  Are wheels the answer?  Is something else the answer?

Comment: There are some discussions on the topic, for example: https://github.com/orgs/python-poetry/discussions/1879 and

Answer (score 2):

I've come up with an approach that seems to work:

1. Use poetry to create a `requirements.txt` file:

```
$ poetry export -f requirements.txt -o requirements.txt --without-hashes
```

2. Install the application's dependencies from `requirements.txt` rather than using Poetry:

```
FROM python:3.10

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT [ "./entrypoint.sh" ]
```

Where `entrypoint.sh` contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 -m blah.cli "$@"
```

To ensure that my `requirements.txt` is in sync with `poetry.lock` I build the container using a Makefile which has been simplified to:

```
VERSION := $(shell poetry version | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
CONTAINER_NAME := blah/blah

requirements:
    poetry export -f requirements.txt -o requirements.txt --without-hashes

container: requirements
    docker build -t $(CONTAINER_NAME):$(VERSION) -t $(CONTAINER_NAME):latest .

.PHONY: requirements container
```

This translates `poetry.lock` into a `requirements.txt` file at build time when the `build` Makefile goal is called and ensures that the two files are in sync when building container images.

Comment: I think it should be possible to take advantage of multi stage builds. In your case the `requirements.txt` could be generated in one stage and installed in the final stage. This way, I think there is no need to worry about keeping the `requirements.txt` up to date.

Comment: I'll see how many lines of code that adds, but, I think that keeping it simple is the way to go for now since I'm not going to be doing builds very often and readability counts.

Answer (score 2):

From the error, `poetry` detect a virtual env in `/app/.venv`, i guess your app not have `.dockerignore` to exclude `.venv` from docker build context, `.venv` on your local also copied into image by `COPY . .`

You can use `poetry` to install dependencies in image also use `poetry` created virtual env as you app interpretor in image as following:

1. `poetry.toml`, is `poetry` setting for project

```
[virtualenvs]
create = true # create virtual env when run poetry cmd
in-project = true # create .venv folder in project root dir for virtual env
```

2. `.dockerignore`

```
.git
.venv
__pycache__
```

3. `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.10

# Add virtual env bin into PATH, use python of virtual env firstly
# Add virtual site-packages into PYTHONPATH, python can find module in it
ENV POETRY_VERSION=1.2.0 \
    PATH=/app/.venv/bin:${PATH} \
    PYTHONPATH=.:src:./.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH

# Install poetry
RUN pip install poetry==${POETRY_VERSION}

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app

# Install dependencies
RUN poetry install

ENTRYPOINT [ "./entrypoint.sh" ]
```