# Fastapi fullstack dockerfile: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'

Tags: docker, fastapi, python-poetry

I created a fastapi docker app based on [this](https://github.com/pyb4430/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql).

After executing `docker compose up`, all worked fine but `backend` and `celeryworker`: they complain about `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sqlalchemy'` (`/app/app/backend_pre_start.py`).

Since the package is managed by poetry, and poetry will create a venv, so I guess the error is caused by environment?

I searched the repo but found no issues similar to mine.

Do I have to manually call `poetry shell` in all `.sh` files?

---

UPDATE

I tried adding `poetry shell`,

now it complains `(25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')`

Comment: your issue should be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/75841882/8582353

Answer (score 0):

I removed `POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=true` and added `poetry config virtualenvs.create false` after poetry installation.

Now poetry won't create a `.venv` when doing `poetry install`, and all dependencies are installed to current directory.